# Does Red wine makes my color fairer?

Tags: food

My friend suggests me that  Red wine makes me fairer.
Please suggest your advice.

Answer (score 1):

This really is a cosmetic question and nothing related to fitness, but I did some checking in on it before I dismissed it out of hand. It turns out that your friend is somewhat right based on [January 2014 study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3936427/).

> Our study suggests that resveratrol significantly inhibits melanin
>   synthesis in vitro and in vivo. These results also support the fact
>   that resveratrol may be a potential skin whitening agent for
>   pharmaceutical and cosmetic use. Further studies are required for
>   clinical and toxicological investigation of resveratrol in the field
>   of skin depigmentation.

The compound being discussed, resveratrol, is found in the skin of red grapes and as such ends up in red (and other) wines. It's also found in blueberries, peanut butter, and dark chocolate. A glass of red wine might have 0.2mg - 2mg of resveratrol, as where a resveratrol supplement pill can have 100x that amount.

Your friend probably saw a boiled down headline about the study I'm referencing, but put some things in context. In this study guinea pigs (not humans) were used, the compound was issued topically (spread across the skin), and alcohol was not added.

I would be *very* wary of relying on alcoholic beverages as a long term net-positive health product.